# gizmo based on Three.js is not visible

Tags: autodesk-forge

I created Forge viewer app w/ Transformation Extension based on GitHub sample "forge-extensions", for unknown reason, gizmo is not visible after I click on element, only very small yellow dot after zoom in, I believe it's element center point and gizmo size is too small, so my question is how to control it? in fact, all the coding is copied from that GitHub sample "forge-extensions", I must miss something simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried your code with different types of models, and does it behave the same for all of them? I believe it may have something to do with the scale of the particular model, especially when looking at [these lines of code](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions/blob/master/public/extensions/TransformationExtension/contents/main.js#L263-L264) from the viewer extension:

```js
_transformControlTx.setSize(
    bbox.getBoundingSphere().radius * 5);
```

Try and put a breakpoint there, and see what the `radius` is. Or try adjusting the hard-coded value.

Comment: thanks Petr, looks like it's working sometimes, even for Autodesk sample model i.e. rac_advanced_sample_project.rvt

Comment: another issue is how to reset to original position after transformation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you please explain what you mean by "to original position after transformation"? How does the extension behave now vs. how do you expect it to behave?

Comment: i mean reset, for instance, i move element in x direction and want to "move back", i tried right mouse click and cannot find that kind of function, perhaps there's more simple way i missed, thanks

Comment: i'm not sure if such functionality is provided by the transform control itself. You'll probably need to store the last position/scale/orientation of an object yourself, and use it to reset the object later if needed.